# how to add ORDER BY or SORTING in the subquery?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

This is the query which contain even the pagination along with this i need to sort by certain column which i specified.

```
DECLARE @RowsPerPage INT = 100, @PageNumber INT =1 
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT a.*,b.WorkflowId bWorkflowId,b.TRF_CompanyCoverage,
b.TRF_OrgID,b.TRF_Fundb_RepoNumber,b.TRF_WSC_PPI,b.TRF_BucketID,b.TRF_GAAPCode,b
.TRF_MarketCapUSD,b.TRF_OrgName,b.TRF_AutomationFlag,b.TRF_SmartPriority,b.TRF_I
ndustryName,b.TRF_ExchangeCountryCode,b.TRF_ExchangeCountryName,b.TRF_UserGroup,
Tasks.TaskId,Tasks.WorkflowId cworkFlowId,Tasks.TRFTaskId,Tasks.TaskName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Tasks.WorkflowID) AS RowNum 
FROM  CCC_Filling_Metadata a,Fundamentals_Metadata b,Tasks 
WHERE a.WorkflowID=b.WorkflowID AND b.WorkflowID=Tasks.WorkflowID AND
Tasks.CreateDateTime >= '2015-01-01' 
AND  Tasks.CreateDateTime <= '2015-12-01' AND Tasks.Owner =  '0326271' AND 
Tasks.TaskStatus = 'open') AS SOD
WHERE SOD.RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage)+1
AND @RowsPerPage*(@PageNumber) 
order by Tasks.TargetDate, Tasks.SmartPriority, Fundamentals_Metadata.TRF_MarketCapUSD desc
```

using this query i am getting exception like this....

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "Tasks.TargetDate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "Tasks.SmartPriority" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "Fundamentals_Metadata.TRF_MarketCapUSD" could not be bound.
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

please help me out how can i use "Order by" in this query...

Answer (score 0):

Your outer query is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM (...) AS SOD
 WHERE SOD.RowNum BETWEEN ((@PageNumber-1)*@RowsPerPage)+1 AND @RowsPerPage*(@PageNumber)
 ORDER BY Tasks.TargetDate, Tasks.SmartPriority, Fundamentals_Metadata.TRF_MarketCapUSD desc
```

So, `Tasks` and `Fundamentals_Metadata` are unknown qualifiers. Remove them since you only have one "view" named `SOD`, so qualification is unnecessary.

Of course, you will need to add `Tasks.TargetDate` and `Tasks.SmartPriority` to the inner query, so they are available for sorting.

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: this error i am getting when i am added inside the inner query

Comment: Of course. As the error says, you cannot specify ORDER BY in the inner query, and I didn't tell you to do that. I told you to remove the *qualifiers* from the ORDER BY clause, and to add the missing columns to the SELECT clause of the inner query "so they are available for sorting".